# VisualStudioCode & Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Hello to all who are working with Powershell and who are interested to move from the Powershell-ISE to VSCode:

I moved with a current project to VSCode, but switched back to the old Powershel-ISE, because of missing some features, e.g. like:
- Intellisense support in Console-window
- theme is not to configure as i need
- the dialog-window does not appear, Credentials must be input in the console 
  instead
- etc.

All in all i have troubles with the different behaivor of CSCode.
To me it seams, the integration of Powershell is not yet ready.
Does somebody has a solution ?
-LD

Comment: Are you running vscode v0.01?  The current version application + extension have all those features and more.

Comment: @Lupus Lupullus Absolutely no problem with these features when last version of VSCode and Powershell extension are installed. User for 1,5 years, I would not come back to Powershell ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Powershell extension for VSCode.

- Within VSCode, click "Extensions"
- Search for "Powershell" and select the Powershell Extension
- Click "Install"

Detailed instructions on how to do this can be found on the [VSCode Powershell extension site.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18089378)

Comment: @Steve I've updated the answer to have more detailed instruction